# Detecting light projections in 2D space using C#

Tags: c#, .net, geometry, 2d, raytracing

A light source is an entity in 2D space that sits in a single coordinate.

There are multiple light sources around in various locations and each gives off 8 rays of light in directions `N, S, E, W, NW, NE, SW, SE`. The coordinates of all lights are known.

Given a random point `(x, y)`, I need to determine if it is being hit by a ray of light.

```
int width = 10000;
int height = 10000;
List<Point> lights = a bunch of randomly placed light sources.
Point position = new Point(8888, 5555);
```

Now I need to iterate the `lights' collection and determine if my location (`position`) is being hit by each.

A simple check for `lights[n].X == position.X` could tell me a horizontal hit and similarly vertical. How do I detect the diagonal hits in the most efficient way possible? Since the diagonal is always at 45 degree angles, can I avoid costly floating point calculations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use:

```
Math.abs(lights[n].X - position.X) == Math.abs(lights[n].Y - position.Y)
```

Using angles (trig functions) will almost definitely be slower and more complex.

Comment: Thanks. Is there also an easy way to determine at which coordinates diagonal rays of light intersect each other for two given points?

Comment: To be fair, I have posted it as another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680222/detecting-light-projections-and-intersections-in-2d-space-using-c-sharp.