# Detecting light projections and intersections in 2D space using C#

Tags: c#, .net, geometry, 2d, raytracing

A light source is an entity in 2D space that sits in a single coordinate.

There are multiple light sources around in various locations and each gives off 8 rays of light in directions N, S, E, W, NW, NE, SW, SE. The coordinates of all lights are known.

I need to calculate all intersections of these rays within the grid.

```
long width = int.MaxValue; // 2D grid width.
long height = int.MaxValue * 3; // 2D grid height.
List<Point> lights = a bunch of randomly placed light sources.
List<Point> intersections = calculate all possible intersections.

for (int i=0; i < lights.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j=i + 1; j < lights.Count; j++)
    {
        // How to compare using integers only?
        // If that is not possible, what is the fastest alternative?
    }
}
```

Comment: First, do you need to obtain a list of all points of intersections or do you just want to know how many intersection points there are? What do you mean by "possible", (intersection points not on the grid) (points that may or may not be intersections to further investigate). Secondly, [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: I want to obtain a list of all intersections within the grid. We already have coordinates for all sources of light (`List<Point> lights`). As for what I have tried, the answer is in the code provided; iteration. What I do not know and is the subject of the question is `how` to compare two points within the bubble sort algo to ensure we cover all 8 rays.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting light projections in 2D space using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679828/detecting-light-projections-in-2d-space-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @jonsca: It's not a duplicate. That is my question too! Different context.

Comment: @RaheelKhan The other question has written out in words `Now I need to iterate the lights' collection and determine if my location (position`) is being hit by each.`  When I looked over this question, it seems like you've just written that out in code here and haven't changed the question any.  If the objective in this case is different, then move the points you made in the comments of the code here out into the main body of the question so that your intentions are known.  Once you've differentiated the two, they will no longer be duplicates and the votes will just age away.

Comment: So each point has 4 rays, in effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer is based off of your comment on a linked question: is there also an easy way to determine at which coordinates diagonal rays of light intersect each other for two given points? It looks like you want to determine the points of the intersection for the rays given by the light sources.

From what you have already described, the horizontal/vertical cases are easy. The points between the two sources describe the intersection. The diagonal cases are more tricky, and I think the easiest way to approach it is just calculating line intersections.

You can describe each diagonal/anti-diagonal as a line described by a vector equation `ray = s + u * d` where `s` is the position of the light source and `d` is the direction of the ray (either `[1, 1]` ,`[1, -1]`, `[1, 0]`, or `[0, 1]`). You have four of such equations for each source, one for each direction. Now, to find the intersection of the diagonal, just find the intersection of the non-parallel lines for the two sources (one pair will be parallel, and so cannot intersection).

Sorry if this isn't clear, I'll try to update this.

**Update**

As a simple optimization, rays intersect diagonally if and only if the [rectilinear distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) (`|x1 - x2| + |y1 - y2|`) between the sources is even. I think there's other conditions that help to simplify your case.

Here's a derivation to find the equations you need. We start with two rays:

```
ray1 = s1 + u1 * d1
ray2 = s2 + u2 * d2
```

In cartesian coordinates:

```
ray1x = s1x + u1 * d1x
ray1y = s1y + u1 * d1y
ray2x = s2x + u2 * d2x
ray2y = s2y + u2 * d2y
```

At the intersection, `ray1x = ray2x` and `ray1y = ray2y`:

```
s1x + u1 * d1x = s2x + u2 * d2x
s1y + u1 * d1y = s2y + u2 * d2y
```

To make things easier, we can isolate and eliminate `u2`:

```
u2 = (s1x - s2x + u1 * d1x) / d2x
u2 = (s1y - s2y + u1 * d1y) / d2y

(s1x - s2x + u1 * d1x) / d2x = (s1y - s2y + u1 * d1y) / d2y
(s1x - s2x + u1 * d1x) * d2y = (s1y - s2y + u1 * d1y) * d2x
```

Then solve for `u1`:

```
(s1x - s2x) * d2y + u1 * d1x * d2y = (s1y - s2y) * d2x + u1 * d1y * d2x
u1 * (d1x * d2y - d1y * d2x) = (s1y - s2y) * d2x - (s1x - s2x) * d2y

u1 = ((s1y - s2y) * d2x - (s1x - s2x) * d2y) / (d1x * d2y - d1y * d2x)
```

To find `u2` you can just evaluate one of equations above or use:

```
u2 = ((s2y - s1y) * d1x - (s2x - s1x) * d1y) / (d2x * d1y - d2y * d1x)
```

So there you have it. Two equations to solve for `u1` and `u2` given the source locations `s1`, `s2` and ray directions `d1`, `d2`. You just plug in `u1` and `u2` values into the original `ray` equations and you have the intersections for one pair. In your case, an intersection exists if and only if `u1` and `u2` are integers. There's one case where a division by zero occurs, when the directions are `[1, 0]` and `[0, 1]`, but that case is trivial to solve (the non-zero coordinates of the sources form the coordinates of the intersection).

Comment: Thank you. That was quite helpful. You mention other conditions that can help eliminate and optimize; how would you Google that? I'm trying to come up with simple conditional checking that covers all diagonal scenarios that does not involve looping through each point on the line.

Comment: For such a specific case, I think you'll have to just think of simple conditions to eliminate unnecessary work. The line intersection method I describe finds intersections in constant time and with only a few arithmetic operations. It's even easier for you because your direction vectors are just `[1, 1]` and `[1, -1]`. I highly recommend it over any sort of looping.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a fixed coordinate plane size, and you will be doing these calculation many times for light sources in different positions, you can do better than iterating over every point.

You can create four bool (or bit) Arrays.

1. Horiz
2. Verti
3. DiagR
4. DiagL

and for each of our light sources, we 'project' them onto those 1-dimensional arrays.
(in the picture I only show two of the projections).

[image]

Projecting onto the Horiz and Verti are simple.

Projecting a point (x,y) on the DiagR array shown in the picture is as easy as x plus y.

Now you could simply walk over all of the grid points, and see if at least 2 of its projections are set to true.

But we can do better,

For instance, in the example we can start by walking over the Verti array.

We notice that Verti[0] is set to true, now we want to see if it intersects with Horiz, DiagR, DiagL.

We compute that to check for an intersection with DiagR (the other array in our picture) we only need to see if DiagR[0], DiagR[1], DiagR[2], and DiagR[3] are true, and we can ignore the rest of that array.

The light of Verti[0] can intersect with horiz at any of its elements.

The light of Verti[0] can intersect with DiagL only at DiagL positions 0,1,2, and 3.

Continue for the rest of Verti[i].

We can now do something similar looking for intersections from the true Horiz[i]'s with DiagR and DiagL.

Lastly, we walk over DiagR and look for intersections with DiagL.

This will return you a list of all intersection points of rays, but which also includes the points of the light sources.

You could either just ignore all intersection points that occur where there are point sources, or use some ingenuity to account for those points.

Comment: Thank you. I do have a fixed coordinate plane size but that size is enormous that the grid cannot be held in memory. Only the light sources are known. Since the grid is so large, even the ray points cannot be held in memory. I can only hold a few thousand intersections, surrounding a point of interest. Would you recommend a vector-based approach here?

Comment: If the size is only 10,000 by 10,000 then this approach only uses 4 additional 1-d arrays of lengths 10,000 10,000 and about 20,000 20,000. And you can make them BitArrays to make these even smaller. You will not need to store the full coordinate plane anywhere in your program.

Comment: But, Zong Li's approach works too in a comparable way, as it was described, it has a very similar nature, comparing the vertical ray of the light source with the diagonal and horizontal arrays, neither of our approaches compare parallel rays against each other, (you could modify Zong Li's approach to not check equivalent equations which result from two light sources being in a line).

Comment: As a final modification of my approach, you could use a hashSets for the 1-d arrays and store only the true values.

Comment: @RaheelKhan Other than that, since I've never really done ray-tracing before, I can't say which approach is going to be better, I would assume mine since it uses array look-ups on pre-computed values in a sequential order, rather than solving for intersection points from pairs of equations.

Comment: edit: I just read your comment again, is your memory really so small you can't hold a "List<Point> interectionPoints" that contains all of the intersections on your coordinate plane?

Comment: If you use the hashSet approach, the size of the 1-d projections will just be based on the number of light-sources in the problem. So with 100 light-sources, the memory used will be around ( 4 times 100 ) plus the size of the list to store the intersection points.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned this in the question (will edit now). The the grid size starts at int.MaxValue in each dimension and grows from there. I tried pre-computing intersections like you suggested (similar to how I pre-compute light sources), but quickly crossed 2GB of memory within 20% of expected iterations.

Comment: @RaheelKhan Also list how many light sources you expect to be using. I'll be out of town for a week, but it may help you get a better answer tailored to the specifics of your situation.

Answer (score 1):

I've lifted the maths from [here](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=geometry2),

Okay so each point has 4 "cardinal rays", a ray being a infinite line that passes between two points.

```
// A line in the form Ax+By=C from 2 points
public struct Ray
{
    public readonly float A;
    public readonly float B;
    public readonly float C;

    public Ray(PointF one, PointF two)
    {
       this.A = two.y - one.y;
       this.B = one.x - two.x;
       this.C = (this.A * one.x) + (this.B * two.x); 
    }
}
```

To get the cardinals we can extend `PointF`

```
private readonly SizeF NS = new SizeF(0.0F, 1.0F);
private readonly SizeF EW = new SizeF(1.0F, 0.0F);
private readonly SizeF NESW = new SizeF(1.0F, 1.0F);
private readonly SizeF NWSE = new SizeF(-1.0F, 1.0F);

public static IEnumerable<Ray> GetCardinals(this PointF point)
{
    yield return new Ray(point + NS, point - NS);
    yield return new Ray(point + EW, point - EW);
    yield return new Ray(point + NESW, point - NESW);
    yield return new Ray(point + NWSE, point - NWSE);
}
```

To find the inersection of two rays we can do

```
static PointF Intersection(Ray one, Ray two)
{
    var delta = (one.A * two.B) - (two.A * one.B);

    if (delta == 0.0F)
    {
        //Lines are parallel
        return PointF.Empty;
    }
    else
    {
        var x = ((two.B * one.C) - (one.B * two.C)) / delta;
        var y = ((one.A * two.C) - (two.A * one.C)) / delta;
        return new PointF(x, y);
    }
}
```

So, to get the intersections for the cardinals of two points,

```
public static IEnumerable<PointF> GetCardinalIntersections(
    this PointF point,
    PointF other);
{
    return point.GetCardianls().SelectMany(other.GetCardinals(), Intersection)
        .Where(i => !i.IsEmpty());
}
```

Which then enables,

```
public static IEnumerable<PointF> GetCardinalIntersections(
    this PointF point,
    IEnumerable<PointF> others);
{
    return others.SelectMany((o) => point.GetCardinalIntersections(o));
}
```

We can then use this functionality like this.

```
var point = new PointF(1.0F, 1.0F);

var others = new [] { new PointF(2.0F, 5.0F), new PointF(-13.0F, 32.0F) };

var intersections = point.GetCardinalIntersections(others);
```

Obviously there is lots of iteration here, I haven't compiled or tested this but since, at its nub, the maths seems fairly efficient I'm optimistic about performance.

Comment: I know this is good OOP practice, but I don't think it's a good idea to create so many objects just to perform line intersection.

Comment: @ZongLi is that because the performance would be slow or becuase it would use additional memory? I'm not convinced of either is significant without testing. However, I did move the instatiation of the cardinal size offsets.

Comment: I think it's just unnecessary in this case to make such distinctions such as `Ray` objects. I believe in this case the object code only serves to obfuscate the one or two equations that are actually being evaluated.

Comment: I'm struggling to visualise a simpler function signature. I guess you are suggesting something like `float[][] Intersections(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)`?

Comment: Actually, nevermind. I think the OP should keep the `Ray` idea and call it `Vector`, representing in coordinates instead of standard form. Also, I just realized there's a slight problem in your code. Since we're working in taxicab geometry, two non-parallel lines do not necessarily intersect (see my answer about rectilinear distance).

Comment: @Zong Li, I believe you are correct, (if I understand.) I guess I'd have to do somthing with `float.IsInfinity` to cater for those cases. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.isinfinity.aspx. For this specialised problem I think I get away with it unless I fall to rounding problems.

Comment: Yes, rounding could be a problem, but I'm referring to the fact that since we're on a 2D grid, a diagonal and anti-diagonal can pass over each over without intersecting.